# Android Studio GoogleMap Application

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for a Google map application on my project and I had no problem to get the map and the GPS location. But when I try to create a search bar to find some place on the map, I can't make it and the application stops. When I start the debug, I get this:

> 06-27 14:31:52.753 17791-17791/com.example.thier.sherpa
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.example.thier.sherpa, PID: 17791
>                                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method
>   onMapSearch(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick
>   attribute defined on view class
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'search_button'
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)

Here is the code of MapActivity.java

```
package com.example.thier.sherpa;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

  }




//--------------------------------------------
public void onMapSearch(View view) {
    EditText locationSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String location = locationSearch.getText().toString();
    List<Address> addressList = null;

    if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Address address = addressList.get(0);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }
 }

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(27.746974, 85.301582);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Kathmandu, Nepal"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

}

Here is the XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"

    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:hint="Search Location Here" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:onClick="onMapSearch"
        android:text="Search" />

</LinearLayout>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.viralandroid.googlemapsandroidapi.MapsActivity" />
```

Comment: Try using normal onClickListener on the button in onCreate?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use PlaceAutocomplete on click of Editext in your app to find a  
location Latitude and Longitude and point it out on Google Map.

/*** Use the Code Snipet***/

locationSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try
            {
                Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN).build(Dosage_Calculator.this);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
            catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == 1)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(MapsActivity.this, data);

            locationSearch.setText(place.getName());

           /* Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());

            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getLatLng());

            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getAddress());*/
        }
        else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR)
        {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(MapsActivity.this, data);

            Log.i(TAG, "Status: "+status.getStatusMessage());
        }
    }
}
    });

And in your AndroidManifest.xml 

Don't forget to add 

 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="Your google_search_api_key"/>

 Note : To create google_search_api_key : Use Link --> https://console.developers.google.com/
```